# Problems with equations enumeration

Tags: math-mode, equations, enumerate

---

I'm writing my thesis using LaTeX and I have some problems with the enumeration of equations. In particular in the first chapter I'm writing a theorem (which is numbered with 2 as I want) but the equation in the theorem is numbered with 0.1 even though I'm writing it in the first chapter. So I get this:
[image]

and I would like the equation to be numbered with 1.1, since it's the first chapter.
I tried to solve the problem with `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}` but I didn't solve it. I also tried to use `\setcounter` but I get the error "no counter 0.0 is defined".
I hope you can help me, thank you in advance.

---

First of all I want to thank you a lot!
I tried to use `\counterwithin{chapter}{equation}` but it didn't work.
I used `\chapter{Introduction}` and `\chapter{Chapter 1}` and `\setcounter{\theequation}{1}`.
This is my code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,noexaminfo,Lau,binding=0.6cm]{sapthesis}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{curve2e}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{lmodern,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{/tikz/>=stealth,/pgf/number format/use comma,compat=newest}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{observation}{Observation}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norma}{\lVert}{\rVert}


\hypersetup{pdftitle={Applications of coding theory to $t$-designs and projective geometry},pdfauthor={}}

\setlength\parindent{24pt}

\title{Applications of coding theory to $t$-designs \\ and projective geometry}
\author{}
\IDnumber{}
\course{}
\courseorganizer{}
\AcademicYear{}
\copyyear{}
\advisor{}
\authoremail{}
\versiondate{\today}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\input{introduction}
\input{chap_1}
\input{chap_2}
\input{chap_3}

\backmatter
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

---

Ok, I solved it! There was a `\mainmatter` missing so it was like everything was written in the introduction, which was actually the first chapter.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you write in your preamble `\counterwithin{equation}{chapter}`?

Comment: How was the first chapter created? `\chapter*`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.  For example, your `\renewcommand` couldn't be expected to work, but `\renewcommand{\theequation}` would be more reasonable.  And it's not clear how you tried to use `\setcounter`.

Comment: Please read through that MWE link closely.  We don't have `chap_1`, so we can't see what you've done.  Your chaptering commands are very suspicious, because they would result in "2. Chapter 1".  Please post a complete example here that we can copy and paste to see the problem you are having.

Comment: You say you tried `\counterwithin{chapter}{equation}`.  That's backwards.  It should be `\counterwithin{equation}{chapter}`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP solved the problem herself (see the edit of the question)